# Flexible Catalogue Management System... is there anything I am missing?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, architecture

I am creating a catalogue management system for my Dads company. The current one, which I have designed and launched over the past couple of years, is good and efficient but it has its limits in the sense that if he wants to add a property to an item type then I have to add it in the database and code behind and relaunch the system.

Now, for the next major version, I am trying to modify this so that he can define all the columns himself - so I have an ItemType table where he names the item types; an ItemTypeProperty table so that he can define all the columns and their datatypes, an Item table where all the items are stored with the ID of their ItemType and an ItemPropertyValue table which uses an ItemID, ItemTypePropertyID and stores the value. The aim is to enable him to say that he wants a column of type  so that, if there are two ItemTypes called Range and Collection, he can say that he wants Collection to be a property of Range.

Has anyone here faced the creation of this kind of system before and, if so, is there anything major I am missing or anything I may want to consider before I get too much further? I mean like some kind of problem I may hit later which I could avoid by doing something now? Alternatively are there any technologies which would be of a lot of assistance? I have tried Linq but found it hard to customise it to my needs at the time. I am currently using VB.Net 2.0 (the limitation set by the server; not under my control) with Sql Server 2008. I have created my own system derived from the MVC kind of architecture.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

Edit:

My new database structure is:

**Table: ItemType**

- ID
- Name

**Table: ItemTypeProperty**

- ID
- ItemTypeID
- Name
- Description
- DataType

**Table: Item**

- ID
- ItemTypeID

**Table: ItemPropertyValues**

- ID
- ItemID
- ItemTypePropertyID
- Value

Comment: "I am trying to modify this so that he can define all the columns himself " - sounds alot like SharePoint!

Comment: Well yeah - it kind of is. I know I could use SharePoint for this but I wouldn't have created it myself then. I would've basically taken a pre-developed product (someone elses work) and customised it to suit the company. I therefore won't feel like it is my work at all and the feeling I get when I see it all come together, knowing it is all my work, is what motivates me to develop it myself.

Comment: whether it's 'all your work' is largely irrelevent. What's important is does it fit the business's needs?

Comment: The current version does - but it is not as flexible as I would like it to be. At the moment it takes a while to add something to it, such as a property of a product. It also takes a fair amount of testing. What I am trying to achieve will decrease these times. Besides there is no time limit on it (as the current version works efficiently and suits the business' needs) and it was my final year project at uni so, to me, whether or not it is all my work *does* matter.

Comment: the schema you are talking about is commonly termed EAV Entity-Attribute-Value, and it can really suck! It kinda defeats using a relational DB.

Answer (score 0):

What are the main architectural drivers here?  How important is maintainability?  How would you compare them to to runtime needs like performance?

This might sound kind of corny - but having a clear idea about what's important and what's not will help you make good decisions.

The reason I say this is because systems where users can define what would 'normally' be something more rigidly set in the application are implicitly more complex and therefore more challenging to work with.  Basically it's a trade-off: some tasks will become easier - others harder.

On the other-hand it's not uncommon to find systems like this - so if you haven't done one before you'll definitely find it a worthwhile experience.  All I'm saying is that if the current design "works" then you should only change it if there is a good reason to.

Specifics:

- Getting the data model right will be important.  Before you go too far make sure you understand the [5th Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form): basically you will (probably) run into issues where two concepts that can't be linked in the real-world can be in your system - because they're all values (ItemTypes) in the same table ([this link](http://www.dataqualitypro.com/data-quality-home/5th-normal-form-the-achilles-heel-of-etl-data-warehouse-proj.html) might be better).
- Reporting will be harder - because you don't have a nice flat table structure to work-off, so you might also get less tool support (just a hunch - totally unsupported opinion).
- You might find yourself putting 'more' constants into your system - if you do just make sure you map them out relatively well in advance (it related to getting the data model right).

**Update:**

> "It seems to work but I won't know
>   until I have multiple ItemTypes and
>   instances of those"

This exactly the point I wanted to make about data modelling.  By data modelling I didn't so much mean physical construction of the DB, but a thorough understanding of the underlying data - the "logical data".  Starting with pen & paper / a white board is a great first step; from that you might well progress into doing some design work using one or more databases to actually try things out before committing to a full system.

> "If a system of this size can be as
>   efficient as it is then why can't
>   this?"

You're probably trying to compare apples and pears.  *Some* reasons:

- Hardware and configuration.  I'm guessing your system and this one aren't exactly the same.
- Architectural priorities: At a guess I'd imagine that this site was built with performance in mind; it's certainly not something you can add as an after thought, however, that doesn't mean  you can't improve the performance of an old system - you certainly can - although it's a specialized skill.
- Caching, Pre-Calculation: using caching is a fairly obvious way of improving performance.  Another is to pre-calculate data in advance of it being requested.  This is something you may want to consider.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Yes I believe I have the database set up correctly. I have so far set up the tables and added a sample ItemType and an "instance" of that with 2 properties in the ItemPropertyValues table - I have also created 2 views, one to get all the properties of a specific ItemType and 1 to get all the property values for an instance of that ItemType. It seems to work but I won't know until I have multiple ItemTypes and instances of those. I will edit my question to display the table structures. Performance is a key factor in this project and currently I don't think the load speed of cont.

Comment: ...the first page (after the application has been recycled) is particularly satisfactory. The current system loads all product records into classes first, then displays the page. This is highly inefficient for the first page (the one where the customer must be attracted to stay on the site) but highly efficient for subsequent page loads. I aim to change this approach in the new system by selecting the relevant records on *each* page, not preloading data into classes.

Comment: Ok I have added the new database structure. What motivated me to give this a try was that the product I am working on at work has over 900 tables, most of which are essential for the product to run. Most of them contain thousands of records. If a system of this size can be as efficient as it is then why can't this?

Comment: Also look at stackoverflow - thousands of questions being asked every day and yet it loads almost instantly the vast majority of the time..

Comment: "the product I am working on at work has over 900 tables" - SAP by chance?

Comment: @Mitch: No, not SAP. It is a product called the i-Grasp, produced by Stepstone Solutions. I know thousands of records is not a lot - but we don't have a lot of records (probably about 2k max) so it is worrying if the one page load which really matters (the decider between most customers staying or leaving) takes longer than the time taken normally for a site of this size. Look at Facebook too - millions (possibly even billions) of users who use it every day / week.. Yet that is quicker than the first page load on my Dads site.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: Design, Indexes, Hardware, RAID levels and placement. Lots of possible reasons for that speed difference.